# Help improve our FAQ page

Tags: discussion

I've just made some changes to our [FAQ page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq), to help new users understand what this site is about. I've also tried to clarify our stance on bug reports.

If you want to suggest any changes to our FAQ page, or discuss the wording, please do so here!

[See the FAQ page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq)

Note: we can only edit the text under *What kind of questions can I ask here?*, so please don't suggest changes to the answers for any other questions, as they are out of our control :)

---

ExpressionEngine Answers - Stack Exchange is a community Q&A site for **ExpressionEngine administrators, developers, designers, and end users**. If you have a question or problem with ExpressionEngine, you're in the right place!

We welcome all well-written questions about using ExpressionEngine CMS or any ExpressionEngine add-ons. Questions must be **answerable** (e.g. no feature requests), and must **not lead to open ended discussions** (e.g. no "which add-on is the best" type questions, unless they have a specific use case described).

Questions which do not directly involve ExpressionEngine (such general HTML, CSS, Javascript or PHP questions) should be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead as they will receive better answers there.

If your problem is clearly a bug, and you can identify which add-on is responsible (such as a PHP error), we ask that you **report it directly to the developer through their official support channels, as there is very little our community here can do to help you**. Even if the developer provides official support via Stack Exchange, you must contact them via email instead.  Questions which are obviously bug reports will be closed. However, if you're not sure whether your issue is a bug, it's ok to ask here whether you're approaching things the right way.

Comment: I think this looks really good. Thanks to everyone who helped shape this! I do see one small typo: the word "as" seems to be missing in the phrase "such general HTML, CSS, ..."

Comment: I think emphasizing that this is ultimately a wiki of solutions helps convey what the question/answer page should strive to be. Oftentimes when we receive or give feedback to new users, we're trying to shape the page. Understanding that this is part forum and part pages that represent solutions, and that we're trying to craft the latter, helps orient the postings.

Comment: Exactly! I've been trying to put that into words for a while. I think it's important to convey that you should try to phrase your question in a way that will help others. Will add shortly.